# Continuum hypothesis and non measurable set

Tags: reference-request, axioms

This is from  Chap 8 of Real and Complex analysis of  Rudin.
[image]

The author does not present a proof  (using the continuum hypothesis) for the existence of the function $j$. Where can I find such a proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The continuum hypothesis says $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$, right?

The cardinal of $[0,1]$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

By definition, $\aleph_1$ is the cardinal of the least uncountable ordinal.  That is, a well-ordered set that is uncountable, and each initial segement is countable.

The last step: if two sets have the same cardinal, then there is a one-to-one mapping from one onto the other.

Comment: what is an initial segment?

Comment: An initial segment of ordered set $W$ is a subset of the form
$\{x \in W \;:\;x < a\}$